# How do I obtain related entities after a concurrency exception in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am following the asp.net contoso university example from concurrency exceptions. Everything works great for a single entity. But when I want to retrieve related entities database values they are null. Below is my exception set up.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
    var clientValues = (Car)entry.Entity;
    var databaseValues = (Car)entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject;
```

I was wondering why this is done the way it is.?
Why not not use find and include to get the car object and its related tables?
Is their a way to get the related tables with the current example code?

I'm using Asp.net MVC5, c#, Entity Framework 6

I tried using

```
 var databaseValues = unitofworkcar.carRepository.FindIncluding(id);
```

which is basically just a function that calls include on all connected tables.
But what I get back is what my client typed in and not the current entries in the database?
How do I correct this?